# Simple Tachyon example fails with "failed to rename" within underFSStorage in GCE

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-compute-engine, alluxio

When running a simple example I get this error.

I tried changing permissions and used different directories.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: FailedToCheckpointException(message:Failed to rename /home/bryan/tachyon-0.7.1/underFSStorage/tmp/tachyon/workers/1445054000001/3/8 to /home/bryan/tachyon-0.7.1/underFSStorage/tmp/tachyon/data/8)
    at tachyon.worker.WorkerClient.addCheckpoint(WorkerClient.java:130)
    at tachyon.client.TachyonFS.addCheckpoint(TachyonFS.java:228)
    at tachyon.client.FileOutStream.close(FileOutStream.java:105)
```

Any ideas?

> My answer below does not actually solve this issue.  It's only a
>   workaround using HDFS as the UnderFS.
>
> My config here uses the local file system:
>
> ```
> export TACHYON_UNDERFS_ADDRESS=$TACHYON_HOME/underFSStorage
> ```

Comment: This is a similar issue. Please try it and let me know if the workaround fix your issue:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tachyon-users/yNY0YflcLvA

Answer (score 0):

I got past this error by first checking my Hadoop version:

```
hadoop version
> Hadoop 2.7.1
```

Then compiling Tachyon for Hadoop 2.7.0:
(for 2.7.1 it would not compile)

```
mvn -Dhadoop.version=2.7.0 clean install
```

And setting `TACHYON_UNDERFS_ADDRESS` to a local HDFS address:

```
nano conf/tachyon-env.sh
export TACHYON_UNDERFS_ADDRESS=hdfs://my-cluster-m:8020
```

This leads to another problem which might affect you (if running single node):

[Tachyon on Dataproc Master Replication Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192125/tachyon-on-dataproc-master-replication-error)